# Magento Theme Package

Tags: magento-1.9, database, theme, sql, deployment

Required database backup files with theme.

I have build custom theme but need to get all static block data as well as cms pages database script and other required layout updates with theme deployment.

**Note: no need to get all database. only required tables and static block, cms pages and layout updates need for theme Deployment.**

Any help welcome and get +1 if some help i will get.

Answer (score 3):

Can you through how to instal date / time update.
This way if you use it with custom theme, the first refresh Magento populate your database with CMS Blocs.

---

Create file and put the content:
app/etc/modules/Namespace_SetUp.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_SetUp>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Namespace_SetUp>
    </modules>
</config>
```

---

Create file and put the content:
app/code/local/Namespace/SetUp/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_SetUp>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </Namespace_SetUp>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <resources>
            <namespace_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Namespace_SetUp</module>
                </setup>
            </namespace_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

---

Create file and put the content:
app/code/local/Namespace/SetUp/data/namespace_setup/data-install-1.0.0.php

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$cms_block_1 = 'lorem ipsum 1';
$cms_block_2 = 'lorem ipsum 2';

$blocks = array(
    array(
        'title' => 'CMS Block Title 1',
        'identifier' => 'cms_block_identifier_1',
        'content' => $cms_block_1,
        'stores' => 0,
        'is_active' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'CMS Block Title 2',
        'identifier' => 'cms_block_identifier_2',
        'content' => $cms_block_2,
        'stores' => 0,
        'is_active' => 1
    )
);

foreach ($blocks as $block) {
    if (Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($block['identifier'], 'identifier')->getId()) {
        Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($block['identifier'], 'identifier')->setContent($block['content'])->save();
    }
    else {
        Mage::getModel('cms/block')->setData($block)->save();
    }
}

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: [@denish vachhani](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/34368/denish-vachhani) 
My answer helped you?